# How does ssis excel data source task know at which row to stop?

Tags: ssis

I have an Excel file with about 500 rows.

The excel data source task reads these rows and SQL destination task inserts 500 rows into the destination table.

If there is a blank row at row number say 400, even then the task doesn't stop at row 400 and keep going until the last row say 500th row.

Curious to know how does ssis excel data source task know at which row to stop?

Comment: There's nothing strange to this. The file itself contains only 500 rows. The source reads those rows without checking whether any of them is empty or not. In fact, that's sometimes a *problem* because empty rows are loaded as actual rows with null values and can cause validation failures.

Comment: Technically excel contain huge number of rows. I was wondering how ssis knows that to stop at 500 (last row having the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the logic is, I cannot say and I doubt it's documented anywhere.

To "see" what the Excel Source is going to consume, assuming you select the worksheet and not a named range. Open the spreadsheet in Excel, hit Ctrl-End once and Excel will navigate to the last cell/column where it might have had data. In your example of 500 rows, it could actually go to row 600 because there *was* data in those cells, or formatting or some artifact where the data is no longer present but some invisible marker is still on the worksheet. Highlighting rows 500-600 and choosing Delete will reset the end of data marker to line 500.

If you find the Excel File Source is reading many blank lines beyond the "end,"  I handle the problem by identifying what defines a valid row of data (ID column is populated, SSN, SalesDate, *something* or *somethings* that define a minimal set of data).

Add a Derived Column: `IsInvalidRow` this will be of type Boolean, DT_BOOL, and I use an expression like `ISNULL(MyCol)` or `ISNULL(MyCol) || MyCol==""` etc, however you determine what an invalid row is.

Add a Conditional Split and use the condition `IsInvalidRow` and route those rows to nothing. Connect the Default path to the rest of your data flow.

### Why do I add an extra column?

Debugging/maintenance/supportability. If an invalid row is going to your destination and you have all that logic in the Conditional Split, you can't look at the evaluation of the the expression. By separating it into an explicit column, you can debug it (usually by breaking down very complex expressions into smaller ones and comparing the output).